# how to create new connection to SQL DB using Visual Studio installed in another computer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

//I am trying to connect through my Visual Studio 2010 to SQL Server installed in another computer. I see the other computer's SQL Server, But when I test the connection it always give me an error message [image]

//do I have to change something in security?> note that I select: allow remote connection to this server

Comment: Check in SQL server config manager. Check that named pipes are enabled for this instance. There are many reasons for this message, but that's the one I run into most often IMHO.

Comment: Also, it might be an idea to start the SQL Server Browser service on the machine that hosts the SQL Server instance, since [that's what it's useful for!](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165724%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Dude for helping me. the SQL server Browser is already started, is there a guide or manual can help me?

Comment: Did you check Named pipes too? I've done a quick Google for you, [here's a good list of things to check.](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)